# GeoDjango query: all point that are contained into a multi polygon

Tags: python, django, django-orm, geodjango

I have two models:

```
Model_A that contains a GeoDjango Point;

Model_B that contains a GeoDjnago MultiPololygon;
```

For every element in Model_A I have to check if the point is contained into some m_polygon of Model_B element;

I'm able to make this simple query.

But I also thought:
I have a lot of elements in Model_A and few elements in Model_B. 
*So, probably is more efficient to iterate all elements in Model_B and check if exist some element in Model_A that it is contained into the current Model_B element*.

So, is there any way to make this GeoDjango query?

Something like this:

```
Model_A.objects.filter(*point_is_contained_into*=a_model_b_mpolygon);
```

**------------------ EDIT -----------------**

I tried to use this:

```
result = Model_A.objects.filter(position__intersects=a_model_b_mpolygon)
```

And this works for me.
Are there contraindications to use this type of query in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Django version 1.11 you have an optimized option to solve this query.

**Assumptions:**

1. `Model_A` has a geometry field called: `model_a_point`.
2. `Model_B` has a geometry field called: `model_b_poly`.

**Methods used:**

1. [`Subquery()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions), new method in Django 1.11 which allows the definition of queries with a subquery part.
2. [`OuterRef()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef), new method in Django 1.11 which is used:

   > when a queryset in a Subquery needs to refer to a field from the outer
   >   query.
3. [`within()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#within), which:

   > Tests if the geometry field is spatially within the lookup geometry.
4. [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset), which will generate for each item in a queryset, a new field (in our case it will contain the points contained by a polygon.)

**Query:**

```
Model_B.objects.annotate(
    contained_points=Subquery(
        Model_A.objects.filter(
            model_a_point__within=OuterRef('model_b_poly')
        )  # Ref: 1, referenced below, keep reading
    )
)
```

**Result and something more:**

The query above will have a field `contained_points` for every polygon in `Model_B` which contains every point from `Model_A` contained by this polygon.

If you only want to keep geometry field of those points (`lon, lan`), at the end of the `Subquery` call (Ref: 1), use the [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) method.