# Relate two models by geometry intersection in Geodjango

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

In GeoDjango with two have two models which contain geometry fields:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models 

class Country(models.Model):
    territory = models.MultiPolygonField()
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class House(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField()
```

I want to make a query that returns all houses located in countries that speak English.
The relation between Country and House should be done by intersecting `House.location` with `Country.territory`.

How can I achieve this using GeoDjango's ORM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A useful and fairly optimized solution would be to combine the English speaking countries' polygons into a [multipolygon](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:multipolygon) (an area produced from at least 2 well defined polygons). Then filter which points intersect with that area.

To do that, we will use GeoDjango's [`Union`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.Union):

> Returns a GEOSGeometry object comprising the union of every geometry in the queryset. ***Please note that use of Union is processor intensive and may take a significant amount of time on large querysets***

inside a [`Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
Houses.objects.filter(
    location__intersects=Subquery(
        Country.objects.filter(language='English')
                       .aggregate(area=Union('territory'))['area']
    )
)
```

Or we can avoid the Subquery (for Django versions < 1.11):

```
engish_speaking_area = Country.objects.filter(language='English')
                                      .aggregate(area=Union('territory'))['area']
Houses.objects.filter(location__intersects=english_speaking_area)
```

---

Another way is to modify a bit of my answer here: [GeoDjango query: all point that are contained into a multi polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166891/geodjango-query-all-point-that-are-contained-into-a-multi-polygon/47263632#47263632) to your needs.