# How could I translate a spatial JOIN into Django query language?

Tags: django, join, orm, gis, geodjango

#### Context

I have two tables `app_area` and `app_point` that are not related in any way (no Foreign Keys) expect each has a geometry field so we could spatially query them, respectively of `polygon` and `point` type. The bare model looks like:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Point(models.Model):
    # ...
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326)

class Area(models.Model):
    # ...
    geom = models.PolygonField(srid=4326)
```

I would like to create a query which filters out points that are not contained in polygon.
If I had to write it with a Postgis/SQL statement to perform this task I would issue this kind of query:

```
SELECT
    P.*
FROM
    app_area AS A JOIN app_point AS P ON ST_Contains(A.geom, P.geom);
```

Which is simple and efficient when spatial indices are defined.

My concern is to write this query without hard coded SQL in my Django application. Therefore, I would like to delegate it to the ORM using the classical Django query syntax.

#### Issue

I could not find a clear example of this kind of query on the internet, solutions I have found:

- Either rely on predefined relation using `ForeignKeyField` or `prefetch_related` (but this relation does not exist in my case);
- Or use a single hand crafted geometry to represent the polygon (but this is not my use case as I want to rely on another table as the polygon source).

I have the feeling that is definitely achievable with Django but maybe I am too new to this framework or it is not enough documented or I have not found the rightful keywords set to google it.

The best I could find in the official documentation is the [`FilteredRelation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects) object which seems to do what I want: defining the `ON` part of the `JOIN` clause, but I could not setup properly, mainly I don't understand how to fill the other table and point to proper fields.

```
from django.db.models import F, Q, FilteredRelation

query = Location.objects.annotate(
    campus=FilteredRelation(<relation_name>, condition=Q(geom__contains=F("geom")))
)
```

Mainly the field `relation_name` puzzle me. I would expect it to be the table I would join (here `Area`) on but it seems it is a column name which is expected.

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'Area' into field. Choices are: created, geom, id, ...
```

But this list of fields are from `Point` table.

My question is: How could I translate my spatial `JOIN` into Django query language?

Nota: There is no requirement to rely on `FilteredRelation` object, this is just the best match I have found for now!

### Update

I am able to emulate the expected output using [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
results = models.Point.objects.extra(
    where=["ST_intersects(app_area.geom, app_point.geom)"],
    tables=["app_area"]
)
```

Which returns a `QuerySet` but it still needs to inject plain SQL statement and then the generated SQL are not equivalent in term of clauses:

```
SELECT "app_point"."id", "app_point"."geom"::bytea
FROM "app_point", "app_area"
WHERE (ST_intersects(app_area.geom, app_point.geom))
```

And `EXPLAIN` performances.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the best solution would be to aggregate the areas and then do an intersection with the points.

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import Union

multipolygon_area = Area.objects.aggregate(area=Union("geom"))["area"]

# Get all points inside areas
Points.objects.filter(geom__intersects=multipolygon_area)

# Get all points outside areas
Points.objects.filter(~Q(geom__intersects=multipolygon_area))
```

This is quite efficient as it is completely calculated on the database level.

[The idea was found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257143/relate-two-models-by-geometry-intersection-in-geodjango)