# geodjango get polygon intersections for each model

Tags: django, django-queryset, postgis, geodjango

I was trying to get locations(polygon) with shops(point). I don't want to add a foreign key reference for location into shop model, rather I want to get location by checking intersections.

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    location = PointField()
    
    @property
    def point(self):
        return self.location.wkt
    

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    area = PolygonField()
```

Iterating over locations I can get what I need, however I am looking for a better approach.

```
for i in Location.objects.all():
    print(Shop.objects.filter(location__intersects = i.area))

## output: 
<QuerySet [<Shop: Shop object (1)>, <Shop: Shop object (2)>, <Shop: Shop object (4)>]>
<QuerySet [<Shop: Shop object (3)>]>
```

I tried using subquery but iterating over full Location queryset returns error `more than one row returned`. so I set the limit to 1.

```
loc=Location.objects.all()
shp=Shop.objects.filter(location__intersects=Subquery(loc.values('area')[:1]))
```

I want to append intersecting locations to my queryset.

Answer (score 0):

got desired output by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166891/geodjango-query-all-point-that-are-contained-into-a-multi-polygon/47263632#47263632). Had to modify a bit.

```
Shop.objects.annotate(
    contained_points=
        Location.objects.values('area').filter(
           area__intersects=OuterRef('location')
    )[:1],
).values()
```